# Need help for proving: $f(f^{−1}(A)) ⊆ A$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Informations:
$f:X \longrightarrow X$ and $A \subseteq X$.

How can i prove this statement:
$f(f^{-1}(A)) \subseteq A$

This is my thoughts until now:

$f^1(A)=\{x\in X |f(x)\in A\} \subseteq X$.

$f(A)=\{f(x)|x\in A\}$

$f(f^1(A))=\{y\in A:\exists \in f^1(A):y=f(x)\} \in A$

Comment: How do you normally show something is a subset of something else?

Comment: You can assume that the domain is not $X$ but some other $Y$, and this still holds.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $x \in f^{-1}(A)$, what does that say about $f(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

First off, welcome to Math SE! It is encouraged here to use LaTeX formatting in your posts; you can find a tutorial [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Second, it is encouraged that when you make a post, you include some information about how you've already tried to solve this problem, and where you're stuck.

For instance, this is a very straightforward problem, and you just need to follow definitions. That is, let $x\in f^{-1}(A)$. What does that mean? If you write out what is immediately implied by the definition, you'll find your proof writes itself.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited it now.

Answer (score 0):

Take $y \in f[f^{-1}[A]]$. So $y = f(x)$, where $x \in f^{-1}[A]$, and the latter means that $f(x) \in A$, so $y \in A$ and the inclusion has been shown.